# mod_rewrite & PHP; $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] vs. mod_rewrite

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, uri, server-variables

Quick one:

I'm curious if anyone knows of certain circumstances under which `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` would contain a different value than `$_GET['_uri']`, given the following `.htaccess` for the latter:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ?_uri=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I've been using the latter method `$_GET['_uri']`, and while I'm aware that `mod_rewrite` would still be necessary, I'd like to get away from storing the URI as a query parameter.

---

Well, I've found one I didn't notice before; when the application bootstrap to which `mod_rewrite` forwards is not in the root web directory, `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` contains the parent directories, whereas `$_GET['_uri']` only contains the latter URI component. Example:

> Bootstrap is **`/subdir/index.php`**
>   Requesting **`http://localhost/subdir/foo/bar/baz/`**
>
> `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`  **`"/subdir/foo/bar/baz/"`**
>   `$_GET['_uri']`            **`"foo/bar/baz/"`**

In order to replicate the result of `$_GET['_uri']`, decided to use this:

```
$prefix = trim(dirname(strtr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], '\\', '/')), '/') . '/';
$uri = trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/') . '/';
if(substr($uri, 0, strlen($prefix)) == $prefix){
    $uri = substr($uri, strlen($prefix));
}
```

But I've not used `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` often in the past, and now have read that it carries certain vulnerabilities and/or inconsistencies with it's use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
http://example.com/meow?param=value&_uri=hihihi
```

- Expected `$_GET['_uri']` result: `meow`
- Actual result: `hihihi`
- `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` value: `/meow?param=value&_uri=hihihi`
- `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL']` value: `/meow`

All because of `[QSA]` flag.

Use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and/or `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL']` instead.

The above is for Apache. On IIS 7.x it may be a bit different.

Comment: Thanks @LazyOne - This is why I'm moving away from it, I need `QSA` for other reasons, namely being able to override other application query parameters (*request type `api`/`web` for instance*). However, do you know of any other issues like as mentioned in my edit?

Comment: @TomcatExodus Those are the only 2 that I'm aware of. I'm usually have to worry about one that I have mentioned as I simply keep ALL rewrite rules in a single place -- either inside <`VirtualHost>` or .htaccess in a root folder.

Comment: Awesome, thanks @LazyOne - I'll let the question sit for awhile, but I can't seem to find any other issues either. I'll mark accepted after I give others a chance to chime in.