# Obtaining the route-able URI part

Tags: php, routes, uri

While almost too related to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6590125/mod-rewrite-php-serverrequest-uri-vs-mod-rewrite), I'll ask as my "question" and intent have changed.

What is the "best" (*accurate, consistent, efficient*) way to obtain the "route-able" part of a URI. By this, I mean the part of the URI representing the virtual directories to be used in the application routing of a PHP application. For example:

> Bootstrap physical path:  **`c:/xampp/htdocs/path/to/app/index.php`**
> Web root path:         **`c:/xampp/htdocs/`**
>
> Given the following request:
> **`http://localhost/path/to/app/foo/bar/baz/`**
>
> Expected result:
> **`foo/bar/baz/`**
>
> ...but `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` contains:
> **`path/to/app/foo/bar/baz/`**

I used to use `$_GET['_uri']` in conjunction with `mod_rewrite` like so:

```
# conditions
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?_uri=$1 [L,QSA]
```

But am now switching to simply:

```
# conditions
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [L,QSA]
```

And have got something like this so far:

```
// get physical uri part, relative to doc root
$uriPhysical = trim(strtr(dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), '\\', '/'), '/') . '/';

// get full request uri, strip querystring
$uriLong = trim(strtr(substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 0, strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '?')), '\\', '/'), '/') . '/';

// chop the physical part off the beginning
$uriRoute = preg_replace('%^' . preg_quote($uriPhysical, '%') . '%i', '', $uriLong);
```

Have I jumped through a buncha hoops for nothing? Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: What's so bad with substr? I assume you know the base URI, just cut it off from the start position where the baseuri ends.

Comment: @hakre - You mean in lieu of `preg_replace`?

Comment: No in lieu of the overall logic. An application should just know it's base URI and than cut it off from the (known) request URI.

Comment: @hakre - Understandably, I could do that, however I'm going for sort of a *CoC* approach to reduce any application configuration and maintain (*this part of*) the project's filesystem mobility.

Comment: Well, what is your convention to specify the base URI of the webroot then? By convention it's a file somewhere in the filesystem. Probably even a symlink.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) in your parsing.